# Can an MS Teams bot be built on .NET Framework and deployed to a Service Fabric Cluster?

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, .net-framework-version, service-fabric-on-premises

I have an MS Teams bot that is built on .NET Core and works OK. However, for *reasons*, I have been asked to port this bot to .NET Framework and deploy it to a Service Fabric Cluster.

Although I can back-port the code to .NET Framework and deploy it to a local Service Fabric Cluster, I am struggling to get the bot to interact with the Bot Framework Emulator (if I use empty strings for the ID and Password, I get Unauthorized errors; if I supply dummy ID and password values, it complains that the Bot is not registered with botframework.com).

Even assuming I get it to work with the emulator, it is not immediately clear to me how I will integrate it with MS teams (since it is not running as an Azure App Service).

So, before I go much further with this, is what I attempting possible, or is this a dead-end?

If it is possible, is there any guidance/documentation available to help me? Everything I can find assumes .NET Core + Azure App Service.

Comment: Why not just use the REAL app id and app password? They're *required* anyway for the bot to be used in Teams

Comment: If I use the id/password of the .NET Core bot, the replies from MS teams get routed via the .NET Core bot, rather than via my local .NET Framework bot.  

How do I create a real app id and password for my .NET framework bot if it is deployed to a service fabric cluster?